# why does the xoom dock connect the USB port?

Tags: charging, motorola-xoom, docking-station

I feel like I must be missing something. I got the Xoom dock from Verizon along with my 4G upgrade (The turn around on the whole thing was 1.5 days, and the 4G is amazingly fast, so, definitely don't put that off if you have that option), and it powers the device AND plugs a USB connector into it (making it kind of tricky to seat correctly on the dock, since the connector is a micro USB). However, the dock doesn't appear to have a USB pass-through, so, it acts EXCLUSIVELY as a charging station! So... why the USB plug and if all it's going to do is charge, I may as well just keep plugging it in!

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Not familiar with the Xoom, but some devices use USB to detect when they're docked, could this be the case?

Comment: I just assumed that it was to keep the Xoom stable in the dock, honestly. Without plugging into something I feel like it wouldn't be very snug in the dock and would fall over when I tap the screen.

Comment: @eldarerathis, that's a reasonable assumption, but it really irritates me that I can't connect it to my computer while its in the dock... Really, this seems like a ludicrous oversight.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous (or you're just good with electronics) you can crack it open and [add your own USB passthrough](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1306811) ;) I agree, though: it's annoying and if it wasn't free with the upgrade I wouldn't gotten one myself.

Comment: unfortunately I am nowhere NEAR this industrious. But it's good to know that this is not something I'm just overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xoom dock has a connector to the USB port for Audio and stability. The back of the dock has a stereo out port.

Here is a link detailing the innards and how to convert to a plain USB. http://wordpress.greghausman.com/2011/05/08/motorola-xoom-usb-dock/

Comment: thanks... yeah, I had a 'duh' moment when I remembered that that's how it passes the audio along. As I said, I'm not handy enough (and not motivated enough), even with the instructions, to modify the USB portion of this... at least not this week, but thanks very much for the link.